# Contact us form error

Tags: php, email

I am using contact us form using php and i am not well known abt php since im working in java now.

I am facing one problem in contact form that is im using 1 php file and contact form html, but the thing is when click the submit button it downloads the php file but it is not sending any mail from the contact form.

But i've mentioned the to mail in the php content page but no process is done.

Can anyone help to do it or share if any process like sending mail from contact form using php? It can be just sample form also.

Comment: If the PHP file is being downloaded, it means the web server is not configured correctly for PHP. You should solve that problem first before trying to troubleshoot your code.

Answer (score 1):

If it is downloading the PHP file, then the server is not processing the file for PHP statements. You need to install PHP on the server and make sure it is properly configured.

Comment: do u mean dat php related servers like xampp right?